# PHP Form Searching MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

currently working on a search form and it's going great, however it's not picking up any of the results successfully.

Here's a screenshot of the database

http://screensnapr.com/e/IdNs9j.png

As you can see there are several results with the word "dragon"

Now if you go to search.php?name=dragon it brings up these results:

```
Results

Sorry, your search: dragon returned zero results

You searched for: dragon

Results
End of results
```

Here's the search query:

```
$searchTerm = trim($_GET['search']);
$query = "select * from item where name like '$searchTerm' order by name";
$numresults=mysql_query($query);
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($numresults);
if ($numrows == 0) {
echo "<h4>Results</h4>";
echo "<p>Sorry, your search: " . $searchTerm . " returned zero results</p>";
}
```

Why is it not displaying any of the results? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu didn't specify the wildcard operators for the `like` operation. Without wildcards, `somefield LIKE 'something'` is exactly the same as `somefield='something'`.

Your query should be

```
SELECT ... LIKE '%$searchTerm%';
                 ^--         ^-- wildcards
```

and note that you're WIDE open to SQL injection attacks. At bare minimum you should have

```
$searchTerm = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);
```

or better yet, switch to using PDO prepared statements.

Comment: thanks, i did originally have the wildcards in place but i was told to remove them since they would just end up causing an error
also, i've added the mysqlrealescapestring as you recomended, thanks i almost forgot about sql attacks :P
as for this topic, the wildcards fixed it, thanks

Comment: They shouldn't cause an error, unless you mis-used them, e.g. something like `... LIKE %keyword%` without quotes, or outside quotes like `... LIKE %'keyword'%`.

Comment: well the original version was /"%$searchTerm%/" but was having issues with old parts of the code that i've now removed, i thought the "like" part of the query was the cause of the wildcard :P